# Does the Novikov self-consistency principle rule you being another conscious observer in history?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, time-travel

The Novikov self-consistency principle at its simplest form is that you can't go back in time and change the past in a way that would affect your existence.

Does that mean that it is automatically incompatible with parallel universes theory? Or does it simply mean that you can't change the past that isn't compatible with your current world-line?

Secondly, does it mean that although even you can't change the past **consistently** with a time machine, you can't be another conscious observer during that time of history, in this case the consciousness of another being in that time of history. For the Grandfather's paradox, that would mean  **your** consciousness could be your Grandfather's consciousness (yes, you became him or his friends or anyone alive and conscious during that point in time) , and doing what they did that would be recorded as history and set in stone?

Comment: Wikipedia says: The Novikov consistency principle assumes certain conditions about what sort of time travel is possible. Specifically, it assumes either that there is only one timeline, or that any alternative timelines (such as those postulated by the many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics) are not accessible.

Comment: There isn't any such thing as a "parallel universes theory."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [Novikov self-consistency principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle) does not say you cannot go back and affect your existence: what it does say is that *any history that is inconsistent will have zero probability*. Going back and killing one's grandfather and hence preventing one's birth will (if the principle is true) fail for one reason or another - or it turns out that grandma was maybe not quite as virtuous as expected, or something else.

People often confuse time travel causing new timelines with parallel universes. This is because the [many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) (real, if contested physics theory) implies that all possible outcomes are represented as real worlds. This appears similar to stories where time travellers change something in the past and return to a changed "present" - it is often assumed that the original timeline somehow exists "out there". But in that kind of story metaphysics it could just as well be that there is only one, constantly edited, timeline: it is fundamentally the author's choice.

The self-consistency principle ensures that inconsistent worlds in the MWI have zero amplitude and hence "don't exist", but *all* the other possible worlds have positive amplitudes.

Consciousness does not seem to have anything to do with the self-consistency principle, or for that matter, quantum mechanics. A brain that follows a [CTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve) into the past may encounter its own worldline, but at that point in time there are just two pretty similar brains functioning normally, although one of the brains may have memories of having been the other brain at the time of the encounter. No weird consciousness, no merging of identities, just all the *other* weirdness that occurs when one allows information to flow into the past.

Comment: "two pretty similar brains functioning normally" that argument is pretty much what makes time travel incoherent. That's the scenario we would like to rule out. Id like to think consciousness is immutable because we don't see doppelganger of people poping up out of nowhere. It's not clean in reality

Comment: If our universe is really a simulation or holographic projection, and if parallel universes doesn't exist, then the only way Nokinov's principle would be useful is that anyone wishing to time travel will have to live as another being  (conscious observer) in that time era.

Comment: @Nederealm - Replace the brains with computers in the thought experiment. Both are running the same instance of (say) Windows with the same serial number, yet computer B has a clock that shows a later time and some other differences in memory. Why would that be incoherent?

Comment: And if it was Windows XP or 7 you get an activation dialog box along with a not genuine label. See my point of coherent. People will tell you that if that it was possible then why isn't such chaos happening right now give that for someone from the future, we are actually in the past and should see such effect of a time traveller

Comment: @Nederealm - The lack of time travellers can most easily be explained by either lack of time travel (e.g. not possible at all) or that we are not in a region of spacetime with CTCs. The self-consistency principle may well imply (although this has proven hard to prove) that one cannot make CTC regions.

Answer (score 0):

"Consciousness" has not yet been defined in a way that is useful to a physicist, so we really don't know what it means.  So instead, consider the possibility that a "time viewer" just peeks out from a point to view the past, that it can only peek into its own past, and that it is neither detectable nor able to influence what it's viewing.  Presumably any information that could be obtained is already encoded in the viewer's "home present" so there might possibly be no paradox.  After all, a good sleuth might be able to deduce what happened in the past without going to the trouble of sending a "time viewer".

Alas, even this minimally-invasive kind of time travel is not quite workable, because the past is as indeterminate as the future.  The present state of the world "now" is indeterminate to the degree demanded by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle.  Those indeterminacies cause predictions of the future to be more and more uncertain, the further out they go.  An often unappreciated fact is that "postdiction" of the past is similarly increasingly uncertain as the present is extrapolated further into the past.  Another way to put it is that there are many, many different past timelines that could have produced  *this* present; and many, many different future timelines that can follow in the future.  The "time viewer" would at best show a segment of one *possible* past timeline that might have led to the present.

Following a CTC (closed timelike curve) into the past seems at first glance to be a somewhat plausible form of time travel, but to avoid paradoxes the traveler would need to be prevented somehow from communicating anything new to his younger self that hadn't already been communicated to the traveler in his personal past.  Perhaps the future could influence the past, but only in a way that leaves the future unchanged.  That would mean that the future and the past are *both* "written in stone", free of quantum mechanical indeterminacy.  But experiments have shown very convincingly that the future and past are indeterminate; so I think even CTC-mediated time travel would be inconsistent with quantum mechanics.

Given the consistency constraint, sending a video camera into the past even via and bringing it back to the present even via a CTC would be essentially the same as buying a video camera, setting it up *now* to record a scene, then storing the camera's memory in a locked safe, and someone opening the safe to view the video a hundred years later -- or like analyzing fossils to deduce what an extinct animal looked like and how it lived.

Comment: So perhaps can we say that if time travel is possible, it is only as far as consciousness swapping? And quantum mechanics should be able to come up with a way - scientifically at least to verify a conscious swop. Because as observers we can't tell the difference

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer.  Consciousness swapping would suffer the same problems as sending anything material into the past - regardless of how consciousness might be defined (scientifically).  So, though time travel and consciousness swapping are fun gimmicks for science fiction, I suspect they will always be fiction.

Comment: I have a spin in superposition at time 0. At time 2 I measure the x-component. At time 3 I use the time-viewer to measure the y-component at time 1. If the time-viewer doesn't interact with the past as you assert, I have now broken the uncertainty relations. If I collapse the state at time 1, I have a device that can be used to send information back in time (e.g. by interfering with a quantum encrypted channel in Morse code).

Comment: Right.  Even the time-viewer violates QM principles.  It doesn't leave much room for time travel of any kind.